# Buffer Reader code to read input file

Tags: java, if-statement, bufferedreader, tokenize

I have a text file named "message.txt" which is read using Buffer Reader. Each line of the text file contains both "word" and "meaning" as given in this example:

"PS:Primary school"

where PS - word, Primary school - meaning

When the file is being read, each line is tokenized to "word" and "meaning" from ":". 
If the "meaning" is equal to the given input string called "f_msg3", "f_msg3" is displayed on the text view called "txtView". Otherwise, it displays "f_msg" on the text view.

But the "if condition" is not working properly in this code. For example if "f_msg3" is equal to "Primary school", the output on the text view must be "Primary school". But it gives the output as "f_msg" but not "f_msg3". ("f_msg3" does not contain any unnecessary strings.)

Can someone explain where I have gone wrong?

```
try {
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("message.txt")));
    String line = "";

    while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
    try {
    /*separate the line into two strings at the ":" */
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ":"); 
    String word = tokens.nextToken();
    String meaning = tokens.nextToken();

    /*compare the given input with the meaning of the read line */
    if(meaning.equalsIgnoreCase(f_msg3)) {
    txtView.setText(f_msg3);
    } else {
    txtView.setText(f_msg);
    }
    } catch (Exception e)  {
    txtView.setText("Cannot break");
    }
    }

}   catch (IOException e) {
    txtView.setText("File not found");
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The language used is java

Comment: Does your text file contain multiple lines - some of which display f_msg3 and some f_msg? In that case, the final line might be deciding what is displayed in txtView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
............
meaning = meaning.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

/*compare the given input with the meaning of the read line */
if(meaning.equalsIgnoreCase(f_msg3)) {
     txtView.setText(f_msg3);
} else {
     txtView.setText(f_msg);
}
............
```

Otherwise comment the else part, then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious error in your code, maybe it is just a matter
of cleaning the string (i.e. removing heading and trailing spaces, newlines and so on) before comparing it.
Try trimming `meaning`, e.g. like this :

```
...
String meaning = tokens.nextToken();

if(meaning != null) {
    meaning = meaning.trim();
}

if(f_msg3.equalsIgnoreCase(meaning)) {
    txtView.setText(f_msg3);
} else {
    txtView.setText(f_msg);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A StringTokenizer takes care of numbers (the cause for your error) and other "tokens" - so might be considered to invoke too much complexity.

```
String[] pair = line.split("\\s*\\:\\s*", 2);
if (pair.length == 2) {
    String word = pair[0];
    String meaning = pair[1];
    ...
}
```

This splits the line into at most 2 parts (second optional parameter) using a regular expression. `\s*` stands for any whitespace: tabs and spaces.

---

You could also load all in a Properties. In a properties file the format `key=value` is convention, but also `key:value` is allowed. However then some escaping might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList vals = new ArrayList();

```
    String jmeno = "Adam";

    vals.add("Honza");
    vals.add("Petr");
    vals.add("Jan");


        if(!(vals.contains(jmeno))){
            vals.add(jmeno);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Adam je už v seznamu");
        }


        for (String jmena : vals){
            System.out.println(jmena);
        }


        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dokument.txt"))) 
    {

      String aktualni = br.readLine();
      int pocetPruchodu = 0;
        while (aktualni != null) 
        {
            String[] znak = aktualni.split(";");
            System.out.println(znak[pocetPruchodu] + " " +znak[pocetPruchodu + 1]);
            aktualni = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
            System.out.println("Nezdařilo se");
    }

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("dokument2.txt"))) 
    {


      int pocetpr = 0;
        while (pocetpr < vals.size()) 
        {

                bw.write(vals.get(pocetpr));
                bw.append(" ");

            pocetpr++;
        }
        bw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
            System.out.println("Nezdařilo se");
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? Usually it is best to explain code and how it relates to the problem/provides a solution. Perhaps you could edit and expand?